# SQL Group By to get 2 columns for a group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below existing table (much simplified version) from which I have to create the results table. I understand that I have to do some complex self join to arrive at the result table, but just cant get it to work. My only other option is to write a program or a PL/SQL procedure, which I want to avoid if possible.

```
PId     From    To      Timestamp field  
1       1       2       8/09/2014  
2       1       2       8/09/2014  
3       1       3       8/09/2014  
4       1       3       8/09/2014  
5       1       3       8/09/2014  
6       2       3       8/09/2014  
7       2       3       8/09/2014  
8       2       4       8/09/2014  
9       2       4       8/09/2014  
10      3       1       8/09/2014  
11      1       3       8/08/2014  
12      2       3       8/08/2014  
13      2       3       8/08/2014  
14      3       2       8/08/2014
```

The requirement is to come up with the count of rows with a From - To combination, both in the forward (Outgoing) and reverse(Incoming) direction. Will greatly appreciation a solution in the form of a query. Note that the last 2 columns also include my comments in paranthesis, next to the expected values. This is for understanding the requirement better.

Results Table:

```
DaysOld     A       B       Outgoing(Comments)  Incoming (Comments)
1           1       2       2(PId: 1,2)         0
1           2       1       0                   2(PId: 1,2)
1           1       3       3(PId: 3,4,5)       1(PId: 10)
1           3       1       1(PId: 10)          3(PId: 3,4,5)
1           2       3       2                   0   
1           3       2       0                   2
1           2       4       2                   0
1           4       2       0                   2
2           1       3       1                   0
2           3       1       0                   1
2           2       3       2                   1
2           3       2       1                   2
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? It's a weird requirement because half of your result set is duplicate.

Comment: Yes, the result tables are going to be used from a reporting point of view, and they wanted to simplify the report SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're after, except it doesn't contain the redundant rows. They could be added by doing a union with a query that switches greatest and least.

```
SELECT LEAST(From,To) AS A, GREATEST(From,To) AS B, 
SUM(CASE WHEN FROM < TO THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Outgoing
SUM(CASE WHEN FROM > TO THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Incoming
FROM table1
GROUP BY LEAST(From,To), GREATEST(From,To)
```

I also assume that From and To cannot be equal.

Just to be complete, the query that contains the redundant rows:

```
SELECT LEAST(From,To) AS A, GREATEST(From,To) AS B, 
SUM(CASE WHEN FROM < TO THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Outgoing
SUM(CASE WHEN FROM > TO THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Incoming
FROM table1
GROUP BY LEAST(From,To), GREATEST(From,To)
UNION
SELECT GREATEST(From,To) AS A, LEAST(From,To) AS B, 
SUM(CASE WHEN TO < FROM THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Outgoing
SUM(CASE WHEN TO > FROM THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Incoming
FROM table1
GROUP BY GREATEST(From,To), LEAST(From,To)
```

Comment: I am comparing the results, just so you know..and also checking if From and To can ever be the same.

Comment: I had to reverse the order of FROM and TO in lines 8 and 9 of your query, but otherwise, it works great. Thanks a lot!